# Where is the chrome directory in Firefox19.02?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am following this article to learn firefox extension development, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Manifest_Files?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL_Tutorial%2FManifest_Files

However I am not able to find the chrome directory under location **C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox**.

I created the **chrome** folder myself but that too does not work...
Its extremely hard to test standalone XUL code without this option. What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@paa: Couldn't find the profile directory either under `C:\Program Files\Mozilla` or under `%APPDATA%`

However I worked around the problem by using this:
`firefox -chrome file:///<path to my XUL...>`

and using relative paths in my XUL files. Hope other XUL developers find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Things have changed since Firefox 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29).

But you can always use the profile directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for firefox's *chrome directory* then you have to extract **Omni.ja**
You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29)

you should place your chrome.manifest file at the root of your app-directory. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration)

use **Komodo IDE**, for developing firefox addon as this IDE itself uses Mozilla code base or you can use it's free version Komodo Edit.